# User Management in Web Application ( Angularjs, spring, hibernate )

Tags: angularjs, spring, hibernate

Logical Question

**Backend implementation**
I am implementing User Management Module in Web application. I have three table User, Role and UserInterce. The user table has ManyToMany relationship with role table and Role table has ManyToMany relationship with User Interface table. So whenever Server return user object, the system will verify it's role and that role has access right to which user interface.

this is background overview of backend implementation.

**Front End implementation**

Whenever user login into the system,server will return user object. I want to implement access control in form basis. e.g. emp role do not have access right to add button where admin role has access right to add button. To implement form based access control i would require to create another table at server side which has information about ui fields and that will be has relationshiop with User Interface table.

can some one provide better way of doing same thing logically ?

Answer (score 2):

If you don't need to have possibility to edditing role's permissions in runtime, the best way is to use spring JSP tag library and build your frontend using spring security tags
http://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/3.0.x/reference/taglibs.html

Otherwise, using some table for storing your permisssions is the only option to do that

Comment: I am not sure but i think i can not use spring tag library with Angularjs so your second solution for which i was thinking. Thanks